# Is it possible for this loop function to enter an infinite loop in c++11 source code?

Tags: c++, c++11

```cpp
template <>
inline bool _Sp_counted_base<_S_atomic>::_M_add_ref_lock_nothrow() noexcept {
    // Perform lock-free add-if-not-zero operation.
    _Atomic_word __count = _M_get_use_count();
    do {
        if (__count == 0) return false;
        // Replace the current counter value with the old value + 1, as
        // long as it's not changed meanwhile.
    } while (!__atomic_compare_exchange_n(&_M_use_count, &__count, __count + 1,
                                          true, __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL,
                                          __ATOMIC_RELAXED));
    return true;
}
```

This is in `c++/11/bits/shared_ptr_base.h: _M_add_ref_lock_nothrow()`.

`__count` only gets a value at first (not in the loop). Is it possible for this loop function to enter an infinite loop?

Comment: "_`__count` only gets a value at first (not in the loop)._": The assumption is wrong. `__atomic_compare_exchange_n` takes a pointer to `__count`, so clearly it may be updated.

Answer (score 2):

The while loop only continues as long as `__atomic_compare_exchange_n` fails. It'll only fail if the value of `__count` doesn't match the value of `_M_use_count`. After it does fail the value of `__count` will be updated to the current value of `_M_use_count` so that the next call to `__atomic_compare_exchange_n` should succeed (assuming another thread hasn't changed the value again).

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fatomic_005fcompare_005fexchange_005fn

Comment: The answer is clear to me, but perhaps should be clarified with an explicit statement that it *cannot result in an infinite loop*, for the explained reason.  Also, to be pedantic, "count" is "__count".  +1 anyway.

Comment: @wearetherobots it shouldn't result in an infinite loop but if another higher priority thread is in an infinite loop and is always changing the value before the current thread gets a chance to call `__atomic_compare_exchange_n` again then it might never complete

Comment: Good point.  From the point of view of this thread, this code would cause the infinite loop, although, strictly speaking, it only "propagates" an infinite loop that is already occuring elsewhere in the program, and not caused by this code.  But it is worth, pointing this out.